# How to change style for radiogroup checked value using extjs 4.2?

Tags: extjs4, radio-group

I want to do the following stuff,

**value no checked:**

[image]

**Value checked:**

[image]

I want to make the option label bold when it is get selected.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/renganathan/SMpq7/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must add the cls class to the items and define the .x-form-cb-checked class

Here ther is a fork of your code with the changes

http://jsfiddle.net/lisssb/VWP4C/

```
.ver_list .x-form-cb-checked{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```